# Make AuthListener wait until for loop has finished

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read the user's data on each login. Since I have a an Firebase AuthListener inside of AppDelegate.swift, the view changes as soon as the user has logged in.

The problem is, that in some cases the view changes faster than data is processed which leads into a screen without the desired data.

In the past I bypassed this by adding: `databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in ... })` to the code which changes the view:

```
if user != nil && currentCar == "auto auswählen" {
                databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
                    if user?.isAnonymous == false {
                        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootPageViewController") as! RootPageViewController
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                        vc.readTimeline()
                        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    } else if user?.isAnonymous == true {
                        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootPageViewController") as! RootPageViewController
                        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    }
})
```

This worked fine, but now that I read my data with the help of a for loop, it won't since the database request is finished earlier than the for loop:

```
databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            for n in 1...snapshot.childrenCount {
                databaseRef.child("users/\(uid)").child(String(n)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                    ...

                }) { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

**How can I make AppDelegate.swift and the AuthListener wait until the for loop has finished?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to wait with going to the new view until all the data is loaded. One way to do that is to count how many of the child nodes have already loaded, and then continue when you've loaded all of them.

In code that'd look something like this:

```
databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let loadedCount = 0

    for n in 1...snapshot.childrenCount {
        databaseRef.child("users/\(uid)").child(String(n)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            loadedCount = loadedCount + 1
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            ...

            if (loadedCount == snapshot.childrenCount) {
               // TODO: all data is loaded, move to the next view
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```